# ¿Cómo retornar un redirect desde un controlador a una URL que permita redirigir a la web indicada en caso que el usuario no esté logeado?

Tags: laravel

Cuando se registra una factura, el sistema le envía un email al usuario, en ese correo hay una URL (Con un código como parámetro), cuando el usuario presiona el enlace, se ejecuta una clase en el controlador, dicha clase es:

```
public function check($code)
{
    if(auth()->check())
    {
        return redirect('home/invoices/'.$code);
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('login?redirect_to=home/invoices/'.$code);
    }
}
```

Donde verifico con un condicional si el usuario está o no logeado en el sistema, el `if(auth()->check())` funciona bien... Pero el `else` no, solo toma el `login` de toda la cadena de texto.

Comment: Disculpa no entiendo bien, ¿A qué te refieres con que el `auth()->check()` no funciona en el `else`? :/

Comment: Cuando el usuario hace click en el enlace, lo lleva a la web, con la clase del controlador verifico si está logeado el usuario o no (Con auth()->check()), si está lo lleva a la URL de la factura (está en el panel de control), eso funciona, pero cuando no está logeado, no funciona, que sería el redirect del `else`, me lleva a la URL pero solo a esta `miweb.com/login` y no toma en cuenta el resto `?redirect_to=home/invoices/'.$code`

Comment: Probablemente tu ruta **login** tiene un nombre, de ser así intentalo con esto `return redirect()->route('login', [ 'redirect_to' => "home/invoices/$code" ])`. Si tu ruta no tiene un nombre, dale uno así, ejemplo `Route::get('login' ... )->name('login')`

Comment: Okey, gracias! ya intento...  No conocía esa opcion para formar rutas.

Comment: No funciona... Sí, la ruta tiene nombre, es el sistema de login por defecto de Laravel.

Comment: Si el controlador tiene un middleware en el constructor, entonces nunca entrará a tu condicional

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó! olvidé conectarme ayer para avisar